# Making first letter uppercase in Laravel breadcrumbs

Tags: php, laravel-4, breadcrumbs

Is there a function or something in laravel which I can use to make first letter uppercase in breadcrumbs?

This is what I'm using right now but in my links and routes are all lowercase letters and if I go and try to update all will be very time consuming..

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li>
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
     <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}">Home</a> /
     @for($i = 0; $i <= count(Request::segments()); $i++)
         <a href="">{{Request::segment($i)}}</a>
         @if($i < count(Request::segments()) & $i > 0)
              /
         @endif
</li>
     @endfor
</ul>
```

Or this isn't correct way of making breadcrumbs in laravel 4.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it with [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) very easily

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
      <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}">Home</a> /
        @for($i = 0; $i <= count(Request::segments()); $i++)
          <a href="">{{ucfirst(Request::segment($i))}}</a>
          @if($i < count(Request::segments()) & $i > 0)
            /
          @endif
    </li>
        @endfor
    </ul>
```

Comment: Sometimes we forget that simple PHP functions do exist within frameworks :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Laravel but you can do this with CSS only.

```
.breadcrumb a {
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
```